# CallKit find number used to start app from native phone app

Tags: ios, callkit

I've implemented CallKit in our app. Calls our app makes are displayed in the native phone app's recents list.

When tapping an entry for our app in the recents list, our app is started. Is there a way to find out which number(/entry) was used to start our app? (openURL or something)

Comment: You can get the solution in Swift 4 [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57375678/2393843). Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll want to implement `application(application: UIApplication, continueUserActivity userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: ([AnyObject]?) -> Void) -> Bool` on the AppDelegate. For this particular action, `userActivity` will have a `interaction` property, with an `intent` property that is an instance of `INStartAudioCallIntent` (or `INStartVideoCallIntent` if your app does video).

The intent object has an array of `INPerson` contact objects on it, which can be used to determine information about what was dialed.

If your app doesn't load any contacts into the system, your calls are one-to-one (as opposed to group) and you just want access to the "dialed number", you'll probably find what you want at `intent.contacts?.first?.personHandle?.value`.

Also note that you'll need to link and import the `Intents` framework.

**Update**

The previous answer was only half-right. There are two ways of getting this information, and both should be implemented.

The continueUserActivity variant above will be called when an item in recents is tapped (or a contact is selected), and *your app is already running*.

However, if your app is not currently running, then it will be launched and `continueUserActivity` will not be called. Instead, the system will invoke your AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` with a `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.userActivityDictionary`, which can be used like:

```
if let activityOptions = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.userActivityDictionary] as? [String: AnyObject],
   let activity = activityOptions["UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityKey"] as? NSUserActivity {
  self.launchWithActivity(activity)
}
```

Once you have the `NSUserActivity` instance, the behavior is the same as it is in `continueUserActivity`

**Update Again**

Per @vivek takrani in the comments below, it appears that `continueUserActivity` may be called at all times, whether the app was previously open or not. I would test this on earlier versions of iOS 10 if you intend to support it, as I don't believe this was the case at the time this answer was written.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed!

Comment: @RasmusHöglund & Colin, when tap on the recents list, my app is not starting and not showing call option in recents. I don't know what I missed?

Comment: It only opens for entries that your app created (by using callkit). Do you have entries that your app created in recents?

Comment: @RJVKumar Also, in order to get your app to show up in the contacts list, and other parts of the system, you must set `supportedHandleTypes` on your `CXProviderConfiguration` to include the types of handles your app supports. This will enable the option to call using your app directly from the contacts.

Comment: Hey, the continueUserActivity method is called all the times, even when the user clicked on a call from call logs & app was closed.

Comment: This may be the case in more recent iOS updates. It always seemed strange that it worked this way before. I'll update my answer to reference your comment.

Comment: Is it compulsory to add Deep Linking functionality to get selected VOIP app number and start audio calling in that app?