# How to get voip phone name description from native phone recents?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, callkit

When I tab the outgoing call made by my app in native phone recents
But I only can get the id (EX: 12345678), can't get the description (EX: David)

[native phone recents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOdDY.jpg)

[info of the outgoing call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckHCD.jpg)

Here is my code in *AppDelegate.m*

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void(^)(NSArray * __nullable restorableObjects))restorationHandler NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0)
{
     INInteraction *interaction = userActivity.interaction;  
     INStartAudioCallIntent *startAudioCallIntent = (INStartAudioCallIntent *)interaction.intent;  
     INPerson *contact = startAudioCallIntent.contacts[0];  
     INPersonHandle *personHandle = contact.personHandle;  
     NSString *phoneNumber = personHandle.value;  
}
```

I can't found any info about the description (EX: David) in INPerson object.

Is there any other way to get the phone description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that.

When you configure your CXProvider object, you specify the supported handle types (CXHandle.HandleType), for example:

```
providerConfiguration.supportedHandleTypes = [.phoneNumber]
```

According to the [CXHandle documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit/cxhandle?language=objc):

> When the telephony provider receives an incoming call or the user
>   starts an outgoing call, the other caller is identified by a CXHandle
>   object. For a caller identified by a phone number, the handle type is
>   CXHandleTypePhoneNumber and the value is a sequence of digits. For a
>   caller identified by an email address, the handle type is
>   CXHandleTypeEmailAddress and the value is an email address. For a
>   caller identified in any other way, the handle type is
>   CXHandleTypeGeneric and the value typically follows some
>   domain-specific format, such as a username, numeric ID, or URL.

You can add a generic CXHandle for an outbound call:

```
 - (instancetype)initWithType:(CXHandleType)type 
                        value:(NSString *)value;
```

but it's not sure whether this info is passed into the `userActivity` that is passed into your app.

EDIT: 
As user102008 noted, you can take a look at [Apple's Speakerbox example](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Speakerbox/Introduction/Intro.html).

To resolve contacts, you can add this call to your intent handler

```
func resolveContacts(forStartAudioCall intent: INStartAudioCallIntent, with completion: @escaping ([INPersonResolutionResult]) -> Void) {
    // Your code here
}
```

EDIT 2:
I have a lot more to learn :( Here's a link with more information:
[CallKit find number used to start app from native phone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39789495/callkit-find-number-used-to-start-app-from-native-phone-app?rq=1)

Comment: "but it's not sure whether this info is passed into the userActivity that is passed into your app" It is. See the Speakerbox sample code.

Comment: You can also attempt to set the name for the call yourself using the `localizedCallerName` property on `CXCallUpdate`