# How to get the voip call log information in application - Call Kit

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

I have implemented call kit in my voip app in which i generate the call logs for incoming or outgoing calls (visible on phone recent tab).
When i click on call logs it will open my app. I've overridden the `UIApplication` delegate method to get the handler.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *restorableObjects))restorationHandler
```

But i unable to get call log related information in `NSUserActivity`.
How i can get the call log information in my app?

Any help much appreciate. Thanks!

Comment: As I understand from your question are you unable to get user info when you clicked on the recents from the phone?

Comment: What "call log information" are you looking for?

Comment: @user102008 I need phone number or call UUID to initiate the new outgoing call.

Comment: @Shubham: See the Speakerbox sample code for how to get the phone number (assuming you put a phone number when you reported it to CallKit in the first call that got put into Recents). The UUID is something you create when you create the new call and should be unique to that new call.

Comment: @Shubham An extension is written for the NSUserActivity to get the contact. You can check it from the Apple example [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Speakerbox/Listings/Speakerbox_NSUserActivity_StartCallConvertible_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017290-Speakerbox_NSUserActivity_StartCallConvertible_swift-DontLinkElementID_22https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Speakerbox/Listings/Speakerbox_NSUserActivity_StartCallConvertible_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017290-Speakerbox_NSUserActivity_StartCallConvertible_swift-DontLinkElementID_22)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Complete solution in Swift 4

You need to configure your app to get continue userActivity called.

- Add supportedHandleTypes property in CXProviderConfiguration

  ```
      let configuration = CXProviderConfiguration.init(localizedName:"Product name")
      configuration.supportedHandleTypes = Set([CXHandle.HandleType.generic])
  ```
- Add NSUserActivityTypes of type INStartAudioCallIntent in Info.plist of your project [image]
- Target Project -> Build Phase -> Libraries add Intents.framework
- Import Intents framework in your AppDelegate
- Below is the code to extract phone number from userActivity

  ```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
      let intraction = userActivity.interaction
      let startAudioCallIntent = intraction?.intent as? INStartAudioCallIntent
      let contact = startAudioCallIntent?.contacts?[0]
      let contactHandle = contact?.personHandle
      if let phoneNumber = contactHandle?.value {
         print(phoneNumber)
      }
      return true
  }
  ```

  Hope this helps You.

Answer (score 4):

We can take **phone number** from **userActivity**,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restora`tionHandler:(void(^)(NSArray * __nullable restorableObjects))restorationHandler{
    INInteraction *interaction = userActivity.interaction;
    INStartAudioCallIntent *startAudioCallIntent = (INStartAudioCallIntent *)interaction.intent;
    INPerson *contact = startAudioCallIntent.contacts[0];
    INPersonHandle *personHandle = contact.personHandle;
    NSString *phoneNumber = personHandle.value;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Call information is encapsulated in the INPerson object, which can be parsed from INInteraction objects.

> When providing contacts to SiriKit, any INInteraction objects
>   delivered to other apps includes the information contained in INPerson
>   objects. Do not include any information that you are not willing to
>   share with other apps.

You have to get the interaction and intent object from the NSActivity object.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
 if let intent = activity.interaction?.intent as? INStartCallIntent,
        let contacts = intent.contacts,
        let value = contacts.first?.personHandle?.value {
            let contactHandle name  = value
            // This is the contact handle, now you can add your business logic.
        }

  return true
}
```