# How to update a video call in Recents Call logs in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

I like to update the localized caller name in Recents call logs once the video call starts and if user taps that particular caller in Recents logs it will again connect with the caller from the application. Like used in imo and Google Duo.

Answer (score 1):

FYI - the below code is written in Obj-C,

**To update the localized the caller name:**

```
CXCallUpdate *callUpdate = [[CXCallUpdate alloc] init];
callUpdate.remoteHandle = [[CXHandle alloc] initWithType:CXHandleTypeGeneric value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", phoneNumber]];
callUpdate.localizedCallerName = displayName;
[provider reportCallWithUUID:callUUID updated:callUpdate];
```

**For Recent call logs**, refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42091850/how-to-get-the-voip-call-log-information-in-application-call-kit)