# How to open app from Callkit recent call log iOS objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, callkit

I want to open my app from the tap on a recent call log of iPhone with CallKit how it is possible please guide me.

[image] 
[image]

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57375678/2393843) is the complete solution. Hope this helps you.